# Form action running without click input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, action

I want the code in the form action to run when I click the input button, but it works every time I refresh the page.

```
<form name="musluk" method="POST" action="<?php $res=mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE kullanicilar SET kredi= kredi +$musluk WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']);?>">
    <input name="musluk" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Kazancı Al">
</form>
```

Comment: It works every time _after_ you've submitted it once... you "refresh" the browser, but it actually sends the last request again. Solution: after POST processing redirect the user to a target page (if you then refresh, it will use the last GET request). This technique is also "GET-after-POST"

Comment: This different way works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a random nonce (number only used once or something like this), like a number with 5 digits, in a hidden input field, and store it in the $_Session. When calling the script in action, check if the correct nonce number was send before running the script.

```
$nonce = rand(1000, 9999) ;
$_SESSION["nonce"] = $nonce ; 

<input type="hidden"  name="nonce" value="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
```

And in the aciton-script run:

```
if(0 === strcmp($_POST["nonce"],$_SESSION["nonce"]){
    $runSuperCode() ;
}
```